# Advice for deploying a C# program with database to work over LAN

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, lan

I've designed a C# game that makes use of an Access .mdb database file to store variables.

The basic idea is that one of the players will 'host' a game, and the other player will join said game, by connecting to the database, reading and writing items into the database. The database is needed to pass variables to and fro the host and client, and both programs check the database regularly for new messages / variables (yes, yes, I couldn't get TCP/IP Remoting to work).

Now, there, the program works fine (mostly the client, since the host modifies only its local database), for as long as the client can find the database file. Currently, the connection string for the client is located in a .ini file, and for the program to work, it (or at least, the server) must be located in the Shared Documents of an XP machine, or the Public Documents of a Vista / 7 machine.

But then some questions occurred to me:

1. What if the client user places / installs it into another folder in the Shared / Public Documents? I suppose there's a code out there that could 'drill' into the Shared Documents folders to find the path for the database, share names included... is there?
2. What about installation? The installer default is always "C:\Program Files\GameName". Could it be set (or locked) to a specific folder into the Shared / Public Documents, by default? And is it even recommended to install it into a Shared Folder, what with problems such as Accidental Deletion?
3. Say, the default is "C:\Program Files\GameName". I could see that a set installation path will solve any connection issues, since every client will look in the same path of the other computer, and it won't matter if it's XP or Vista. Could "C:\Program Files\GameName" be accessible by a C# program over LAN, without any system modification? Are there any security (UAC?) issues?

P.S. Details that people may find in handy:
I'm using Visual Studio 2005. So is my School.
I'm running .NET framework 2.0. So is my school, and unfortunately, I can't change that.

Comment: What you are doing is insane. Ditch access. Ditch direct client access to the database. Take a while to learn how to expose data correctly (yes, probably via a web service). You'll benefit tremendously by downing tools on your game and spending a little while learning how to handle data correctly.

Comment: If you feel direct sockets is beyond your reach do yourself a favor and abstract out this layer. IE create an interface to program against to get these messages. Later when you feel sockets isn't as bad as you thought, you can simply swap out the implementation, You'll save a bit of headache as well.

Comment: Hi I don't think using Access is the biggest issue here, since the data is not critical and does not contain large data. However your application is definitely not commercially ready! I had never seen people using Shared or default something to share folder. You should use TCP/IP instead for your point 1)2)3)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll look into the suggestions. Actually, this isn't a commercial project, and more of a hardcore 3-hour programming exercise, although I do get what you guys are saying. I simply wanted it to work 'presentably' and I'll fine tune out the details after I receive my grade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate to tell you this, but this is why the approach is fundamentally flawed.  What are you going to do when:

- File and print sharing on the server is disabled?
- The network client is disabled on a client computer?
- The server is configured to only allow authenticated users, and the client doesn't have access?
- File and print sharing is blocked because of the firewall?
- File and print sharing is completely borked for other who-knows-why reasons?
- You need administrator access on the server to share a folder, but the current user is not an administrator?
- The Access database engine isn't installed correctly on the server or client?
- One of the clients corrupts the database? (This is easier than you might think; all it takes is a network glitch where a client temporarily or permanently disconnects from the server).

These are fundamental issues that you can't resolve with the current solution.

Get it working over normal TCP/UDP ports.  You'll have a much easier time.  There are libraries to facilitate that, see [C# Game Network Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855/c-sharp-game-network-library) - for example it sounds like Microsoft's XNA SDK has functions for networking in a game.  If you use a standard method / standard library to implement networking, your odds of success are much higher.  Using a client/server architecture means that the server's state won't be corrupted if a client goofs up.

I realize that this probably involves a significant rewrite.  Frankly, I don't think you have a choice if you want this game to be commercially successful on a wide customer base without high support costs, and move beyond being a mere experiment.

Comment: It was stated in my system limitation that the network must be up and operational, the sharing must be enabled, the program allowed through the firewall, and the users using the program (host or client) be administrators (as with any game).

I tried TCP/IP remoting before I tried doing databases. Asynchronous socket programming was a headache. Clearly, my skills aren't that advanced yet. I haven't tried Synchronous, although I don't think it would be applicable for this (it'll hang unless it receives something? Yikes).

Comment: So apparently this is homework - I see.  My advice still stays the same - if you want to learn how to make a game that would be commercially successful, the MS Access approach simply won't work.  And the "system limitation" you were given that you can assume the user is an administrator is NOT accurate, either.  Most gamers these days don't run with an administrator token these days due to Vista/7 UAC.  You need to get it running if they are not administrator.

Comment: The limitation that sharing must be enabled isn't realistic, either.  About all you can assume these days is that an Internet connection exists that can make outgoing connections.  Incoming connections might not be possible due to firewalls (Windows firewall, NAT, etc.).

Comment: Search Google for C# game network library, and I'm sure you'll find a number of possibilities that can abstract away the socket-level stuff so you don't have to deal with it.  I mentioned XNA as an example but if you can't use it because your VS2005 is too old, then find one that will work with your platform.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the access database. The described architecture is already 'user unfriendly'

Use either SQL Express or SQL CE which requires no installed database binaries (they can all be included in the applications folder). This way the db will stay in the applications folder (ideally app_Data) and .Net has included support for databases in this folder.

Please stay away from access you will save yourself a lot of trouble.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already tried SQL (well, SQL Server Express 2005, anyway). I had to deal with all the installation, Username, Password, Instance, SQL / Windows Authentication, TCP/IP configuration, and SQL Browser issues. It was nowhere near user friendly, at least not for me, and most definitely not the user, since we are to assume the user has no server knowledge.

That said, I'll be looking into SQL CE... I just hope good ol' .NET 2.0 supports it.

Comment: with sql ce you dont need any of that - so thats a benefit : )

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, if SQL CE does not require an installer, how does it function over a network?

Comment: ah cr@p I think I missed that part about this being your central state sharing mechanism. I thought it was local for each instance. In that case simply go to a socket client (tons of samples on the net) or sql express. You can easily serialize a state object (IE some class) to send off to the receiver as a string and deserialize it. You could also just use WCF and start up an endpoint to listen for a call. These are all better than access.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is little point in using Access unless you wanted to use any of the pretty form-based IO that you can you do with its designer. And I doubt that'll be the case here.

I would encourage you to replace all your file IO with a sound data access layer. 
Which will rid you of all the "sharing" issues that you are experiencing, file locks, the overcomplicated installation process, etc.

Alternatively to SQL Server Express as suggested above you could also use SQLite  http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. SQLite sounds intriguing. I may give it a go, but because this is a 3-hour project, I'll stick with Access for awhile, at least until I can get the program done right.